# XPath query returning 'false' in SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an xml fragment as such:

```
<meta_tree type="root">
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Content Provider</meta_cat>
        <data>Mammoth</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Genre</meta_cat>
        <data>Games</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Channel Name</meta_cat>
        <data>Games Trailers</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Collection</meta_cat>
        <data>Strategy</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Custom 1</meta_cat>
        <data>PC</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>DRM Protected</meta_cat>
        <data>N</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Aspect Ratio</meta_cat>
        <data>16:9</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Streaming Type</meta_cat> 
        <data>VOD</data>
    </meta_data>
</meta_tree>
```

which I garnered from the snippet of `$meta_tree->asXML()`.

So given that, I need to have an xpath query for each element, so I'm using:

```
$meta_tree->xpath("/meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']");
```

but this returns false.

I have tried:

- `/meta_tree/meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']`
- `//meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']`
- `meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']` (this returns an array, but the array is empty)

I've been using [AquaPath](http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/), which validates my query, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone got any ideas?

DJS.

EDIT: As per Tolomak's suggestion, here's some more info.

The  element is a fragment of a larger doc, as follows (names have been replaced with *** to protect the innocent):

```
<contents total_items="1" xmlns="http://rxml.***.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://rxml.***.com/xsd/*Ingestion.xsd ">
     <content item_id="451195">
         ...
         <meta_tree type="root">
             ... see snippet above ...
         </meta_tree>
    </content>
</contents>
```

I retrieve the  fragment above by:

```
$dom = new SimpleXMLElement(... xml_string ... );
foreach($dom->content as $content)
{
    $contentMetadata = $this->getMetadata($content->meta_tree)
}

public function getMetadata($meta_tree)
{
    echo $meta_tree->asXML();
}
```

**ANSWER:** problem was the default namespace. I have chosen to strip them out rather than deal with the namespace, unless anyone knows how to register the xmlns default namespace in SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: Possibly relevant: what version of PHP and libxml are you using? (a [phpinfo](http://php.net/phpinfo)() page will tell you)

Comment: Can it be that you omitted the tiny but relevant fact that your XML is in a namespace?

Comment: @salathe libxml: 2.7.3, PHP 5.2.9-2 (Win)

Comment: @Tomalak I've added some more info about the XML in the question, including a possible clue to your suggestion... but still not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the default namespace. I have chosen to strip them out rather than deal with the namespace, unless anyone knows how to register the xmlns default namespace in SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$meta_tree->xpath("meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']")
```

e.g.

```
<?php
$meta_tree = new SimpleXMLElement(getData());
$foo = $meta_tree->xpath("meta_data[meta_cat='Content Provider']");
var_dump($foo);

function getData() {
  return '<meta_tree type="root">
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Content Provider</meta_cat>
        <data>Mammoth</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Genre</meta_cat>
        <data>Games</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Channel Name</meta_cat>
        <data>Games Trailers</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Collection</meta_cat>
        <data>Strategy</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Custom 1</meta_cat>
        <data>PC</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>DRM Protected</meta_cat>
        <data>N</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Aspect Ratio</meta_cat>
        <data>16:9</data>
    </meta_data>
    <meta_data>
        <meta_cat>Streaming Type</meta_cat> 
        <data>VOD</data>
    </meta_data>
  </meta_tree>';
}
```

prints

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["meta_cat"]=>
    string(16) "Content Provider"
    ["data"]=>
    string(7) "Mammoth"
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run this, I get an array, but it is empty when I run count(...);